# solvePnP with Unity3D

Tags: opencv, unity-game-engine

I have a real/physical stick with an IR camera attached to it and some IR LED that forms a pattern that I'm using in order to make a virtual stick move in the same way as the physical one.

For that, I'm using OpenCV in Python and send a rotation and translation vector calculated by solvePnP to Unity.

I'm struggling to understand how I can use the results given by the solvePnP function into my 3D world.

So far what I did is: using the solvePnP function to get the rotation and translation vectors. And then use this rotation vector to move my stick in the 3d World

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(x, z, y));
```

It seems to work okay when my stick is positioned at a certain angle and if I move slowly...but most of the time it moves everywhere.

By looking for answers online, most of people are doing several more steps after solvePnP - from what I understand:

1. Using Rodrigues to convert the rotation vector to a rotation matrix
2. Copy the rotation **matrix** and translation **vector** into a extrinsic matrix
3. Inverse the extrinsic matrix

I understand that these steps are necessary if I was working with matrix like in OpenGL - but what about Unity3D? Are these extra steps necessary? Or can I directly use the vectors given by the solvePnP function (which I doubt as the results I'm having so far aren't good).

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but the answer to the question "what about Unity3D? Are these extra steps necessary? Or can I directly use the vectors given by the solvePnP function"

is:

-No, you can't directly use them. I tried to convert rvec using Quaternion.Euler and as you've posted, the results were bad.

-Yes, you have to use Rodrigues, which converts rvec correctly into a rotation matrix.

-About inversing the extrinsic matrix: it depends.
If your object is at (0,0,0) in world space and you want to place the camera, you have to invert the transform resulting from tvec and rvec, in order to get the desired result.
If on the other hand your camera has a fixed position and you want to position the object relatively to it, you have to apply the camera's localToWorld matrix to your transform resulting from rvec and tvec, in order to get the desired result